# How can I write if conditions on quantum registers using qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

There is a quantum register measured to state $\left|00\right> $ How can i write a code to check weather the first qubit in measured state is 1 or zero and if 1 do some operations or if 0 do other operation (example).

Answer (score 2):

If *"some operations"* in your question means quantum operations, then you can use [`Gate.c_if()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.Gate.c_if.html) to apply a gate based on a value in a classical register as follows:

```
qr = QuantumRegister(2, 'q')
cr = ClassicalRegister(2, 'c')
circ = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
circ.h(0)
circ.barrier()

# Measure first qubit to cr[0]
circ.measure(qr[0], cr[0])
# Apply X-gate to second qubit if the measured value equals 1
circ.x(1).c_if(cr[0], 1)
# Apply Y-gate to second qubit if the measured value equals 0
circ.y(1).c_if(cr[0], 0)
```

The circuit looks like:

[image]

---

If, however, you mean classical operations, then you can do something like that:

```
# This function will be called if the measured value of first qubit equals 0
def func_0(bit_string):
    print('In func_0 =>', bit_string)

# This function will be called if the measured value of first qubit equals 1
def func_1(bit_string):
    print('In func_1 =>', bit_string)

# Specify how many times you want to run your circuit:
shots = 10

result = backend.run(circ, shots = shots, memory = True).result()
readouts = result.get_memory()

for bit_string in readouts:
    # Check the value of first qubit.
    # Note that Qiskit uses little-endian bit ordering
    if bit_string[1] == '1':
        func_1(bit_string)
    else:
        func_0(bit_string)
```

Comment: So If  want to use some other functions that i built in python, I have to just see weather measured quantum states are $\left|0\right> $ or $\left|1\right> $ then I have to pass in to two different functions based on $\left|0\right> $ or $\left|1\right> $  in python.(from there its pure classical) I just need to see the qubits measured are either 0 or 1.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you well. Could you update your question and add some code to demonstrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: I believe OP is trying to trigger python functions rather than conditionally apply gates, they require `m = circ.measure(...)` which they can use in a python if condition `if m == 0`

Comment: Exactly same but for quantum register suppose if I measure a two qubit state  and found result is  $\left|01\right>$  then I have to check those qubits are either 00 or 01 or10 or11, and make them as input  for  some other functions that are classical based on first qubit is zero  $\left|0\right> or 1 $\left|1\right>$ I  need to  pass to different functions.

Comment: I'm still not sure whether I understand you well. Check my updated answer and let me know if it does not answer your question.